# getPointerCount() doesn't always recognize that a pointer has been released

Tags: android, multi-touch

Everything seemed to go excellent with my multitouch navigation-system in Android until I discovered that, not always but sometimes, when a finger was released, then this event was not recognized by the core of the application.

I put on-screen traces and I realized that at time when a finger is lifted up while the other fingers don't change their position (not even by one single pixel in x or in y axe) then the getPointerCount() doesn't decrease its value as it should, but returns the correct value once at least one of the other fingers is slightly moved.

Bellow, is the code that simulates this effect (a completed, very simple one-class-project) and the APK is also available for manual installation ([www.liknongames.com/apps/MultiTouch.apk](http://www.liknongames.com/apps/MultiTouch.apk)). Please for your feedback, since it is a stopping-issue for me.

The application in the apk, reports in a header-textview (textView[0]) the active pointers, the current action (masked and un-masked) and a counter for the calls of the onTouchEvent( ) method.

```
package com.example.moultitouch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{ 
    TextView[] textView = new TextView[6]; // 0:common metrics 1-5:finger details   
    int pointersCount = -1;
    int action = 0;
    int actionMasked = 0;
    String actionString = "NOT INIT";
    Display display;
    int iViewWidth = 0;

    int motionsCounter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_motion_event);
        display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        iViewWidth  = display.getWidth();
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);       

        for ( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
        {
            textView[i] = new TextView(this);
            textView[i].setWidth(iViewWidth);
            textView[i].setTextSize(16);
            textView[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            textView[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            layout.addView(textView[i]);
        }
        textView[0].setText("Touch the screen to start");
        setContentView(layout);
    }

@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
{
    int i = 0;
    pointersCount = event.getPointerCount();
    action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    motionsCounter++;
    actionMasked = event.getActionMasked();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) 
        actionString = "DOWN";
    else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN ) 
        actionString = "POINTER DOWN";
    else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP ) 
        actionString = "POINTER UP";
    else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE )
        actionString = "MOVE";
    else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP )
    {
        actionString = "ALL UP";
        pointersCount = 0;
    }
    else
        actionString = "UNKNOWN(" + action + ")";

    textView[0].setText (pointersCount + " POINTERS. ACTION:[" + action +"] " + actionString + ". (MASKED:" + actionMasked +"). " + motionsCounter + " MOTIONS");

    for (i = 0; i < pointersCount; i++)
    {
        int x = (int) event.getX(i);
        int y = (int) event.getY(i);            
        int id = event.getPointerId(i);
        textView[i+1].setText("idx: " + i + " id: " + id + ". (" + x + "," + y +")");
    }
    for ( i = pointersCount; i < 5; i++ )
        textView[i+1].setText("- - - - - ");
    return true;
}
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

finally, I found it! Indeed the issue with the method remains and whenever the user places two fingers and lifts the one while keeping the other absolutely unmoved on the screen, then the getPointerCount() still returns 2 and not 1, until the remaining finger slightly changes its position even by making a tiny change in the pressure. The fix, follow this algorithm:

1: In every touch-event, keep in an array the x/y coordinates for all pointers and for all reported count of pointers (no matter if it is correct or not)

2: call the getActionIndex() to get the index of the pointer that last reacted on the screen.

3: in case where the (masked) action is ACTION_POINTER_UP, compare the pointerCounter with its previous value. If it is the same, then this is the case where "...intervene, we must!" So, in this case, starting from that index, pull all the elements inthe arrays x/y with the coordinates by one index.

4. manually, decrease by 1 the variable that keeps the pointers-count.

Issue is closed. Thank you.

```
 package com.example.moultitouch;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Display;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
 final static int MAX_SUPPORTED_POINTERS = 5;

 TextView[] textView = new TextView[MAX_SUPPORTED_POINTERS+1]; // 0:common metrics 1-5:finger details
 Display display;

 int pointersCount        =  0;
 int prevPointersCount    =  0;
 int actionMasked         =  0;
 int iViewWidth           =  0;
 int lastLiftedPointerIdx =  0;

 // just for tracing reason.
 String actionString = "NOT INIT";
 String sHeader = "";
 String sAlarm  = "";
 int motionsCounter = 0;

 int[] touch_x   = new int[MAX_SUPPORTED_POINTERS];
 int[] touch_y   = new int[MAX_SUPPORTED_POINTERS];
 int[] pointerID = new int[MAX_SUPPORTED_POINTERS];

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_motion_event);
     display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
     iViewWidth  = display.getWidth();
     LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);       

    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_SUPPORTED_POINTERS+1; i++ )
    {
      textView[i] = new TextView(this);
      textView[i].setWidth(iViewWidth);
      textView[i].setTextSize(16);
      textView[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
      textView[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
      textView[i].setText("_");
      layout.addView(textView[i]);
    }
    textView[0].setText("Touch the screen to start");
    bThreadForDisplay = true;
    setContentView(layout);
 }


 @Override 
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
 {
      int i = 0, j = 0;
      prevPointersCount = pointersCount;
      pointersCount = event.getPointerCount();
      pointersCount = pointersCount > MAX_SUPPORTED_POINTERS ? MAX_SUPPORTED_POINTERS : pointersCount;

      // for ACTION_POINTER_DOWN or ACTION_POINTER_UP as returned by getActionMasked(), 
      // returns the associated pointer index. 
      lastLiftedPointerIdx = event.getActionIndex();
      actionMasked = event.getActionMasked(); 

      for (i = 0; i < pointersCount; i++)
 {
      int x = (int) event.getX(i);
      int y = (int) event.getY(i);          
      touch_x[i] = x;
      touch_y[i] = y;
 }

      motionsCounter++;
      if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) 
           actionString = "DOWN";
      else if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN )
           actionString = "POINTER DOWN";
      else if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP )
      {
           if ( prevPointersCount == pointersCount )
           {
                sAlarm = " ALARM ON ID " + lastLiftedPointerIdx;
                for ( int k = lastLiftedPointerIdx; k < pointersCount-1; k++ ) // from that point, elevate everything by one position 
                {
                     touch_x[k]   = touch_x[k+1];
                     touch_y[k]   = touch_y[k+1];
                     pointerID[k] = pointerID[k+1];
                }
                pointersCount--; // correct the counter.
                prevPointersCount = pointersCount;
           } // alarm case
           actionString = "POINTER UP";
      }
      else if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE )
           actionString = "MOVE";
      else if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP )
      {
           actionString = "ALL UP";
           pointersCount = 0;
      }
      else  actionString = "UNKNOWN(" + actionMasked + ")";

      sHeader = pointersCount + " POINTERS. ACTION:[" + actionMasked +"] " + actionString + ".  " + motionsCounter + " MOTIONS. " + sAlarm;
      if ( actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP )
           sHeader += sAlarm;
      textView[0].setText (sHeader);

      for (i = 0; i < pointersCount; i++)
           textView[i+1].setText("IDX: " + i + " ID: " + pointerID[i] + ". (" + touch_x[i] + "," + touch_y[i] +")");
      for ( i = pointersCount; i < MAX_SUPPORTED_POINTERS; i++ )
           textView[i+1].setText("- - - - - ");

    return true;
 }
 }
```